# Dynamic Select Box - Populate avaliable options based on previous selection - Rails & AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Dynamic Select Box - Populate avaliable options based on previous selection - Rails & AJAX

I've been trying to create a dynamic select box on my profile form where based on the university a student selects, the form automatically provides the appropriate grading scales to select as a sub select box. However the secondary selectbox (ratings) never populates..argh

Can anyone see what i'm missing here?

Routes

```
resources :student_profiles do
    get 'update_ranks', as: 'update_ranks'
  end
```

Models

```
rating.rb
    class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :university_name
    end

university_name.rb
    class UniversityName < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ratings
    end
```

Controller

```
class StudentProfilesController < ApplicationController

before_action :require_user
respond_to :html, :json
def edit
@universitynames = UniversityName.all
        @ratings = Rating.all
       @studentprofile = StudentProfile.find(current_user.student_profile.id)
  end

  def update_ranks
    @ratings = Rating.where("university_name_id = ?", params[:university_name_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
  end 
End
```

Edit-View

```
<%= s.select :universityname, options_for_select(@universitynames.collect { |country|
    [country.name.titleize, country.id] }, 1), {}, { id: 'universitynames_select' } %>

                            <%= s.select :initialgpa, options_for_select(@ratings.collect { |rating|
    [rating.name.titleize, rating.id] }, 0), {}, { id: 'ratings_select' } %>
```

studentprofile.js.coffee (javascripts/updateranks.js.coffee)

```
 $ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#university_names_select', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_ranks',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        country_id: $("#university_names_select option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic country select OK!")
```

updateranks.js.coffee (student_profiles/updateranks.js.coffee)

```
$("#ratings_select").empty()
  .append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @ratings)) %>")
```

_rating.html.erb - partial (Ratings/_rating.html.erb)

```
<option value="<%= rating.id %>"><%= rating.name.titleize %></option>
```

I have a feeling its to do with my routes but I'm really not experiences in AJAX or JS at all...

Comment: Do you see any changes happening in rails console where the server is running when you select an option? Because in the view you have defined this: `{ id: 'universitynames_select' }` as the id of select box, where as in your js code you are using `#university_names_select`, which will not trigger the ajax call.

Comment: aha! it was the mismatch in ID's which then lead me to needing to update the routes resource!

Comment: So is it working now? and you can also change: `$("#universitynames_select option:selected").val()`, to: `$("#universitynames_select").val()`;

Comment: perfect, it works! Thanks Sahil